# Expected method signatures in trait error messages

Tags: rust

I'm trying Rust and finding it hard to interpret what to do when my function signatures don't correspond to those expected by a trait. Example

```rs
 impl std::fmt::Display for MyType {
    // Not sure what to put here so I stub it and hope to get help from error
    fn fmt() -> () { } 
 }
```

The compiler error message is

```
method `fmt` has a `&self` declaration in the trait, but not in the impl
```

What I was hoping to see was something helping me implement the method for example:

```
Incorrect method signature for `fmt`
Actual signature    fn fmt() -> ()
Expected signature  fn fmt(&self, &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error>
```

Is it possible to get signature help from the compiler like this? I'm usually very impressed by the very friendly and detailed compiler errors, so this one really surprised me. I'm using the rust playground (https://play.rust-lang.org/) but I don't think that makes any difference to compiler output.

Comment: Note: this is [E0186](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0186), and a quick search through the issues does not find it, so there might not already be an issue to improve this error. In general, Rust diagnostics are quite amazing in terms of quality given the (lack of) maturity of the compiler, but they do need some more love.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. If you think this is an important feature, you can always submit a feature request to [Rust issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues).

Meanwhile, you can use docs generated by rustdoc, e.g. [these](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) for the standard library. They are usually pretty awesome, especially given that there is search function.

Comment: Thanks. Issue is submitted (not sure I did that right, but I'm sure I won't be flogged I didn't. The Rust community is fantastic).
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28011

Comment: Please send general feature requests to the RFC repo instead. This case is borderline: it's more of an improvement, so I think it's fine on the main repo

Comment: Thanks Steve, the contributing.md doc wasnt very clear - from what I could make of existing tickets the rfc repo looked like mostly language spec changes and more issues looked like mine in /rust.